# google maps api infowindow content class not triggering jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using google maps api v3, I add a marker to the map with an infowindow with html content and a link w/custom class. I want a jquery trigger to execute upon clicking the link custom class but i've tried many different ways and nothing is working..

Here is my code:

```
function addMarker(mapArray) {

    var techs = mapArray.techs;
    var techlinks = mapArray.technamelink;
    var address = mapArray.address;
    var starttime = mapArray.starttime;
    var endtime = mapArray.endtime;
    var id = mapArray.id;
    var lat = mapArray.lat;
    var lng = mapArray.lng;
    var client = mapArray.client;
    var project = mapArray.project;

    var title = techlinks + "<br /> <a class='addresszoom' data-lat='" + lat + "' data-lng='" + lng + "' style='cursor: pointer; font-weight: normal; color: black;'>" + client + "<br />" + starttime + " - " + endtime  + "<br />" + address + "</a>";

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), map: map, title: techs });

    marker.id = id;
    markersArray.push(marker);

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    addInfoWindow(marker, title);

}

function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: message
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            map.panTo(marker.position);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.close();
        });
    }
```

jquery:

```
$(".addresszoom").click(function() {
        var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
        var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
        alert('it worked');
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        map.setZoom(12);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is creating a click event handler on a dynamically created element.

Try this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".addresszoom", function() {
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
    alert('it worked');
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    map.setZoom(12);
});
```

> [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)